# Запрос SQL если последняя дата recorded_at была более 10 дней назад?

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста с запросом SQL. Мне необходимо получить по 1 записи если последняя дата recorded_at была более 10 дней назад от текущей даты?

```html
SELECT 
   gauging_stations.id,
   gauging_stations.slug,
   gauging_station_records.gauging_station_id,
   gauging_station_records.recorded_at 

FROM gauging_stations

JOIN gauging_station_records

ON gauging_stations.id = gauging_station_records.gauging_station_id;
```

объединил две таблицы с нужными полями, но не могу понять как теперь условие сделать правильно, кому не сложно помогите плиз

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE recorded_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2iYJcuJ.png да но, как теперь исключить записи у которых были  изменения в интервале 10 дней? они сейчас выводятся

Comment: Не понял вопроса. В каком интервале?